# Should the google api key be private?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm using the Google maps embed developer tool for a website, and to use it I have to put this into the html:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Metropolitan%20Grill%2C%202nd%20Avenue%2C%20Seattle%2C%20WA%2C%20United%20States&key=my_api_key">
</iframe>
```

I've replaced my actual Google api key with 'my_api_key' in the src url. Is there any reason I should be concerned about having my api key showing up in the html like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to keep your console key for the embedded API private (you can't, it has to be in the HTML, which is publicly available).  You control the domains that it is valid for, make sure they are owned and controlled by you.